# Ionic-Native, Angular 6, Ionic 4 - Facebook and Google Signin Issue - Object not a Function

Tags: facebook, google-plus, angular6, rxjs6, ionic4

I am attempting to login using cordova plugins with Google Plus and Facebook. Both of these npm packages are giving me the issue:

core.js:1598 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at index.js:245
    at Object../node_modules/@ionic-native/facebook/index.js (index.js:313)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/app/services/auth.service.ts (chunk-fe7f197d.js:144)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/app/pages/login/login.page.ts (pages-login-login-module.js:115)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/app/pages/login/login.module.ts (pages-login-login-module.js:21)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:81)
    at $_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object:37
    at index.js:245
    at Object../node_modules/@ionic-native/facebook/index.js (index.js:313)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/app/services/auth.service.ts (chunk-fe7f197d.js:144)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/app/pages/login/login.page.ts (pages-login-login-module.js:115)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/app/pages/login/login.module.ts (pages-login-login-module.js:21)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:81)
    at $_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object:37
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4053)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)

My Info is:

@ionic/cli-utils  : 2.0.0-rc.6
   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.0.0-rc.6

global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

@angular-devkit/core       : 0.6.0
   @angular-devkit/schematics : 0.6.0
   @angular/cli               : 6.0.1
   @ionic/schematics-angular  : 1.0.0-rc.6
   Cordova Platforms          : none
   Ionic Framework            : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-alpha.7

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   NodeJS            : v8.9.4
   npm               : 6.1.0
   OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : D:\SumTech Solutions\Software\Android_SDK

This becomes an issue only when i add the Imports to the constructor in my auth.service.

Comment: What `@ionic-native/facebook` version have you installed? Make sure to use the latest v5 beta. However, I'm having the same issue with a custom written plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar problems with other native plugins, i got a solution from 
[here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-native-plugin-problem/136670), this may help you.

Update your native libs to 5.0.0-beta.14, each of them inclusive @ionic-native/core

```
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.0.0-beta.14",  
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.0.0-beta.14",
```

While using in app use

```
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
```